# Can Android Build Tools always be up to date (instead of specifying version)

Tags: android, build-tools

Okay, lets say you had an app, that you built with build Tools Version 21. Now, version 24 is out. Your app runs fine. But, there may be optimizations and changes to the build tools that your app does not have when it builds.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
...
```

My question is, is there a way to directly set the `buildToolsVersion` to latest version.

Should you even update the build tools over time. Does it make any difference?

---

Just, to be clear, I am not trying to elicit opinions. More what is the standard model when dealing with build tool updates. Should I wait till I need something from the new version or keep updating for optimizations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. By default, the Android SDK uses the most recent downloaded version of the Build Tools. If your projects depend on older versions of the Build Tools, the SDK Manager allows you to download and maintain separate versions of the tools for use with those projects.

From: [Android Build Tool](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/revisions/build-tools.html)

**EDIT**

I didn't test it, but there are scripts to do it.

It may help you: [SDK and Build Tools Autodetect](https://github.com/aayvazyan-tgm/autodetect_android_sdk_and_buildTools)

Comment: But my question is ... Is there any way of telling Android studio. Hey I always want the latest build tools. AFAIK When you start a project it gives you a version and you're stuck with that unless you manually update it